# How to keep tracked Image Target model object after tracking lost?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am developing AR application with Unity3d and Vuforia. I want to keep ImageTarget object that tracked found when It was lost. How to keep tracked Image Target model object after tracking lost?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean when you lose sight of the ImageTarget, you want the object to stay rather than disappear?

Comment: @bpgeck, Yes. I mean that. 
1. Image Target tracking found and show object.
2. ImageTarget found was lost, but I want to keep it object. I mean. I want to  keep showing object and change it's position.

Comment: I just posted an answer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You can enable **Extanded Tracking**. This post explains it in more detail: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/creating-ar-trackables/keeping-object-screen-even-when-target-lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script that handles what happens when tracking is lost is called `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs` and is found in Assets > Vuforia > Scripts. In that file you will find a function `OnTrackingLost()` This function disables all the `renderComponents` and `colliderComponents` for each of the children of the ImageTarget. If you want your object to **stay visible** comment out the following `foreach` loops like so:

```
private void OnTrackingLost()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
    Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

    /*
    // Disable rendering:
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = false;
    }

    // Disable colliders:
    foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = false;
    }
    */

    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
}
```

Comment: but when I do so the model object stick to the edge of the screen when I move camera out of target.

Comment: @Dungeon Correct. That is a downside of this approach.